# Why the time cann't be update when using setInterval?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am learning AngulaJS, here is the code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app>
    <head>
        <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/angular-1.0.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </head>

 <body>
    <div ng-controller="ClockCtrl">
      Current time is: {{ time.now }}
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

the script.js:

```
function ClockCtrl($scope){
    var time = {};
    time.now = new Date().toString();
    $scope.time = time;
    setInterval(function(){
        $scope.time.now = new Date().toString();
        console.log(time.now);
    }, 1);
}
```

But i don't know why the time cann't be update in the html display?

Comment: Might want to use Angular's [$interval](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval). Out of curiosity, what's with `time` and `$scope.time`? Why not use `$scope.time` directly?

Answer (score 0):

You should use [$interval](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval) directive instead of `setInterval`, which will internally call `$scope.$apply()` to update the bindings

```
function ClockCtrl($scope, $interval){      
    $interval(function(){
        $scope.time.now = new Date().toString();
    }, 1000);

    ////Or, You can use $scope.$apply() 
    //setInterval(function () {
    //    $scope.time.now = new Date().toString();
    //    $scope.$apply();
    //}, 1000);
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/nLs2kw3c/)

Comment: I don't know why show this `Current time is: {{ time.now }}`?

Comment: @BlackMamba, It seems you have not declare angular app, do it like `angular.module('myApp', []).controller(ClockCtrl)`